# How do I create a new line in a properties file using java?

Tags: java, properties-file

I'm trying to update a properties file with java. The file should be structured like this:

```
IDs = \
11:22:33:44:55:66:77,\
11:22:33:44:55:66,\
1C:BA:8C:20:C5:0A
```

But all I get is:

```
IDs=11\:22\:33\:44\:55\:66\:77\:88,\\\njj\:jj\:jj\:jj\:jj\:jj\:jj\:jj,\\\n55\:55\:55\:55\:55\:55\:55\:55,\\\n
```

I just couldn't find out a lot about writing properties file with java and I'm completely lost. An other problem is that the ":" is escaped automatically, how can I prevent this?
The code I'm using:

```
String str = "";
for (User u : values){
    str = str + u.getId() + ",\\"+"\n";
}
prop.setProperty("IDs", str);
```

Comment: Show us the code of your program.

Comment: Almost definitely won't help your problem, but please use a StringBuilder rather than string concatenation there. repeated concatenation like that in Java is very wasteful.

Comment: @moreON: not any more. I have seen loops with `+` to be faster on modern JVMs than a StringBuilder

Comment: @Venyla: don't add the `"\\"` in your loop. Adding just the `"\n"` should be enough.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is that a compiler or jit optimisation? Either way, It's one less innocent-looking thing that can hide unexpected O(n^2) and that's good to have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A backslash at the end of a line in a properties file means that the property value continues at the next line. So your property is equivalent to

```
IDs = 11:22:33:44:55:66:77,11:22:33:44:55:66,1C:BA:8C:20:C5:0A
```

That's what you should set as the property value. Unfortunately, Properties will never format it on multiple lines as you would like it to be. It will take the backslashes and \n that you store in the property as part of the property value, and will thus escape them. So all you should do is accept for the value to be on a single line, and simply set the property value to `"11:22:33:44:55:66:77,11:22:33:44:55:66,1C:BA:8C:20:C5:0A"`.

Comment: You can absolutely put a newline into a properties value. And it will come out as a newline when you use `getProperty()`

Comment: Ok I think this is acceptable but the ":" is still escaped? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It will be unescaped when reading the properties file. You shouldn't care about that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: right, if you put a newline into a property value, it will be transformed into a backslash followed by n in the file, and that sequence will be transformed back to a newline when reading the file. But the OP would literally want a single-line property value written on separate lines in the file, and that will thus not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `commons-io` library, `true` in `(sting1, file, true);` is telling the function to append.

```
  String sting1 = "IDs = \\";
    String sting2 = "11:22:33:44:55:66:77,\\";
    String sting3 = "11:22:33:44:55:66,\\";
    String sting4 = "1C:BA:8C:20:C5:0A";

    File file = new File("{filePath}");

    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(sting1, file, true);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(sting2, file, true);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(sting3,file,true);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(sting4,file,true);
```